# Ace Editor: Why does the theme/mode not change?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying to introduce [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding) to my website - which basically works - but for some reason I cannot change the them to the one I want.

From the [Kitchen Sink](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) I wanted to set "Tomorrow Night Bright" as theme and the mode for Assembly x86.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <title>...</title>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #editor { 
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
        <script>
            require.config({
                baseUrl: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
                    + window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/"),

                paths: {
                    ace: "scripts/lib/bower_components/ace/lib/ace"
                }
            });

            require(["ace/ace"], function (ace) {
                var editor = ace.edit("editor");
                window.alert(editor);
                editor.setTheme("scripts/lib/bower_components/ace/lib/ace/theme/tomorrow_night_bright");
                editor.getSession().setMode("scripts/lib/bower_components/ace/lib/ace/mode/assembly_x86");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor">
section .text
    global main         ;must be declared for using gcc

main:                   ;tell linker entry point

    mov edx, len        ;message length
    mov ecx, msg        ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1          ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4          ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80            ;call kernel

    mov eax, 1          ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80            ;call kernel

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg         ;length of our dear string
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason I cannot see the change. All I got is a simple white text editor:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is what I got. I tried to change the theme when my page loads. This works:

```
var ace_root = "scripts/lib/bower_components/ace/lib/ace/";

require.config({
    baseUrl: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
        + window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/"),

    paths: {
        ace: ace_root
    }
});

require(["ace/ace"], function (ace) {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme(ace_root + "theme/tomorrow_night_bright");
    editor.getSession().setMode(ace_root + "mode/assembly_x86");
});
```

but this does not work:

```
var ace_root = "scripts/lib/bower_components/ace/lib/ace";

require.config({
    baseUrl: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
        + window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/"),

    paths: {
        ace: ace_root
    }
});

require(["ace/ace"], function (ace) {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme(ace_root + "/theme/tomorrow_night_bright");
    editor.getSession().setMode(ace_root + "/mode/assembly_x86");
});
```

The difference is if I put / to ace_root (working) or not (not working). I don't know if that's intended or what the reason. [Get the full HTML document I used here](http://pastebin.com/zyrha1fu).

Browser: Firefox 41.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You have to load : "ace/ext/language_tools" :

```js
require(["ace/ace"], function (ace) {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    window.alert(editor);
    ace.config.loadModule('ace/ext/language_tools', function() {
        editor.setTheme("scripts/lib/bower_components/ace/lib/ace/theme/tomorrow_night_bright");
        editor.getSession().setMode("scripts/lib/bower_components/ace/lib/ace/mode/assembly_x86");
    })
});
```

I hope it will solve your issue !

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer - I was just playing around with the paths as I noticed how I can make it work. [I've added my solution to an issue on github.](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1017)

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors in chrome developer tools? Most likely ace tries to load theme and mode from a wrong place, since you already have ace defined in require paths use `setMode("ace/mode/assembly_x86");` instead of `scripts/...`

Comment: Like above: Thanks for your answer - I was just playing around with the paths as I noticed how I can make it work. [I've added my solution to an issue on github.](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1017)